# Sorting of list depending on frequency in descending order

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of numbers list:
    [1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]. 
I want to sort it by the frequency of elements to get this:
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2].

If several elements have the same frequency, sort them by descending value. Can you find any way to do this. I'm using mentioned method but getting my output as:[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3].

```
from collections import Counter 
list = [1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
c = Counter(list)
x = sorted(c.most_common(), key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0])) 
y = [([v] * n) for (v, n) in x]
z = sum(y, [])
print(z)
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you need to use `reverse=True`

**Ex:**

```
from collections import Counter 

data = [1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
c = Counter(data)

data.sort(key=lambda x: (c[x], x), reverse=True)
print(data)
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

if your list is long, you may want to have to sort only the items that occur the same amount of times:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import groupby

lst = [1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
c = Counter(lst)

ret = []
for key, group in groupby(c.most_common(), key=lambda x: x[1]):
    items = sorted((item for item, _ in group), reverse=True)
    for item in items:
        ret.extend(key * [item])
print(ret)
# [1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2]
```